# I encountered the following error when using typeorm's @Entity()

Tags: typescript, electron, decorator, typeorm

I encountered the following error when using typeorm's @Entity():

database/entity/User.ts:3:2 - error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1.

Why can't I use decorator?

My tsconfig.json is as follows:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2020",
        "useDefineForClassFields": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,

        /* Bundler mode */
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",

        /* Linting */
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "electron/*"],
    "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
}
```

Comment: change typescript version. select version 4 instead of 5.